# How to change numbering style in word 2010 image caption

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I use roman numbering for Header 1 style in my word 2010 document. Then I use the chapter's number for the pictures' numbering. So that the first picture in second chapter would be captioned as Figure 2.1, the second picture as Figure 2.2, and so on. The problem is because I use roman numbering for Header 1, I get Figure II.1, Figure II.2, and so on. How I can I change it? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you use chapter-figure numbering in a caption, the numbering is inserted using fields like this:

```
{ STYLEREF 1 \s }.{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1 }
```

where "1" means built-in style "Heading 1"

I think in this case you will have to insert a { SEQ } field at the beginning of each chapter (e.g. in the chapter heading) like this

```
{ SEQ Chapter \h }
```

then replace the { STYLEREF } field by another { SEQ } field like this:

```
{ SEQ Chapter \c }
```

(You could put * ARABIC in there like the other field, but it isn't really necessary)

There are other possibilities, but that's probably the simplest. You'll need to check that Tables of Figures, corss references etc. work as expected (I think they do).

Comment: How to do that? I mean, do I have to change the view or something?

Comment: Use alt-F9 to toggle between "field code view" and "field results view". You can use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code braces {  } . Everything else is normal text that you can type. Once you have set up the fields you need, you can select them and save them as a building block or autocorrect for easy insertion.

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work :( Now the caption becomes Figure .1

Comment: You have to select the fields and press F9 to update them (its the same for the other SEQ fields, if not the STYLEREF field.